Interpreting the magnitude of vectorial phasors
In fields of physics such as acoustics and electromagnetism, we often deal with physical quantities that are both vectorial and oscillating. These can be represented as vectorial phasors,
$$
\vec{b}(t)
    = \begin{bmatrix}
          |b_x| \mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}\varphi_x} \\
          |b_y| \mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}\varphi_y} \\
          |b_z| \mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}\varphi_z}
      \end{bmatrix} \mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i} \omega t} ,
$$
whose real part represents the actual physical quantity.
The magnitude of a complex vector is defined via the dot product of the vector and its complex conjugate:
$$
|\vec{b}|
    = \sqrt{\vec{b}\cdot\vec{b}^*}
    = \sqrt{|b_x|^2 + |b_y|^2 + |b_z|^2} .
$$
However, I am wondering how this magnitude should be interpreted for general vectorial phasors. Let me give you two simple examples in 2D, where the first has an straightforward interpretation and the second does not.
Example 1: 2D vector components in phase
If both components have the same phase (i.e., $\varphi_x = \varphi_y = \varphi$), the vectorial phasor simplifies to
$$
\vec{b}(t)
    = \begin{bmatrix} |b_x| \\ |b_y| \end{bmatrix} \mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i} (\omega t + \varphi)} .
$$
In this case, $\vec{b}(t)$ oscillates back and forth, always pointing along the same line. An example from acoustics is the particle displacement in a plane wave, as this animation by Dan Russell shows:

The magnitude $|\vec{b}| = \sqrt{|b_x|^2 + |b_y|^2}$ has a straightforward interpretation here: It represents the maximum length of $\vec{b}(t)$, which occurs whenever $\omega t + \varphi = \tfrac{n}{2}2\pi$.
Example 2: 2D vector components a quarter-turn out of phase
If there is a quarter-turn ($2\pi/4$) phase difference between two components, the vectorial phasor can be written as
$$
\vec{b}(t)
    = \begin{bmatrix} |b_x| \\ -\mathrm{i} |b_y| \end{bmatrix} \mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i} (\omega t + \varphi)} .
$$
In this case, the physical (i.e. real-valued) part of $\vec{b}(t)$ traces out an ellipse, which has a width $2|b_x|$ along the $x$-axis and a width $2|b_y|$ along the $y$-axis. An example of this from acoustics is the particle displacement in an evanescent wave, as another animation by Dan Russell shows:

In this case, the magnitude $|\vec{b}| = \sqrt{|b_x|^2 + |b_y|^2}$ is still the same as for the first example, but the interpretation of the first example does not apply here.
How can the magnitude $|\vec{b}|$ be interpreted in this case? And how can the magnitude of vectorial phasors be interpreted in general?

I am not sure there is a good general geometric interpretation of the vectorial magnitude.  If you really want an interpretation that is generally valid, perhaps a better approach would be to generalize your second case, as shown below.
Revising your notation slightly and limiting ourselves to two dimensions, we may write
$$ \vec b = \left[\begin{matrix} b_x \\ b_ye^{i\Delta} \end{matrix}\right]e^{i\omega t+i\phi}, $$
where $b_x$, $b_y$, $\Delta$, and $\phi$ are assumed to be real.  Then the real part would be given by
$$ \Re\{\vec b\} = \left[\begin{matrix} b_x\cos(\omega t+\phi) \\ b_y\cos(\omega t+\phi+\Delta) \end{matrix}\right]. $$
One can then show that $\Re\{\vec b\}$ is a parametric form of an ellipse that has been rotated by and angle $\psi$, where
$$ \tan(2\psi) = \frac{2b_xb_y}{b_y^2-b_x^2}\cos(\Delta). $$
Your two cases are (1) the case where $\Delta=0$, and (2) where $\Delta=\pi/2$ (which leads to $\psi=0$).
Expressions may be found for the major and minor axes in terms of $b_x$, $b_y$, and $\Delta$, but I have not found a particularly illuminating form for these.  However, it may be easily seen that a minimally bounding rectangle of the ellipse has dimensions of $(2b_x)\times(2b_y)$.  Thus, the vectorial magnitude $\sqrt{b_x^2+b_y^2}$ is half the length of the diagonal of the smallest bounding rectangle with sides that are parallel to the $x$ and $y$ axes.  (See the figure below, where the black box is the bounding rectangle for the case of $b_x=1$ and $b_y=2$.)

Finally, I might add a thought about a non-geometric interpretation.  The square of these oscillating functions is generally associated with the energy of the signal.
For example, in acoustics the particle velocity $\vec v$ is often of interest and may be written in the form of $\vec b$.  The kinetic energy density of the wave may then be written as
$$\mathcal{E}_k = \frac{1}{2}\rho\vec v\cdot\vec v,$$
where $\rho$ is the mass density.  If we let
$$ \vec v = \Re\{\vec b\} = \Re\left\{\left[\begin{matrix} b_x \\ b_y \\ b_z \end{matrix}\right]e^{i\omega t}\right\}, $$
now allowing $b_x$, $b_y$, and $b_z$ to be complex, we then obtain
$$\mathcal{E}_k = \frac{1}{2}\rho\frac{\vec b\cdot\vec be^{2\omega t} + 2\vec b\cdot\vec b^* + \vec b^*\cdot\vec b^*e^{-2\omega t}}{4}. $$
Averaging over a period, we may then write the average kinetic energy density as
$$\langle\mathcal{E}_k\rangle = \frac{1}{4}\rho\vec b\cdot\vec b^* = \frac{1}{4}\rho |\vec b|^2. $$
